# Select a record from millions of records slowness

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, optimization

I have a standalone table, we insert it's data through a weekly job, and retrieve data in our search module.

the table has around 4 millions records (and will get bigger) when I execute the straight forward select query it take long time (around 15 second). I am using MySql DB.

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `myTableId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxes` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persons` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalPerPerson` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dayId` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myTableId`)
);
```

When I run the following statement it take around 15 second to retrieve results.
So, how to optimize it to be faster.

```
SELECT 
    tt.testTableId,
    (SELECT 
            totalPerPerson
        FROM
            myTable mt
        WHERE
            mt.venueId = tt.venueId
        ORDER BY totalPerPerson ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS minValue
FROM
    testTable tt
WHERE
        status is NULL;
```

Please note that testTable tble has around 15 records only.

Comment: Try changing the subquery to `select min(totalPerPerson) etc`

Comment: Do you have a sorted index on totalPerPerson and venueId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT tt.testTableId,
       (SELECT mt.totalPerPerson
        FROM myTable mt
        WHERE mt.venueId = tt.venueId
        ORDER BY mt.totalPerPerson ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as minValue
FROM testTable tt
WHERE status is NULL;
```

For the subquery, you want an index on `mytable(venueId, totalPerPerson)`.  For the outer query, an index is unnecessary.  However, if the table were larger, you would want in index on `testTable(status, venueId, testTableId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MIN` and `GROUP BY` may be faster.

```
SELECT tt.testTableId, MIN(totalPerPerson)
FROM testTable tt
INNER JOIN mytable mt ON tt.venueId = mt.venueId
WHERE tt.status is NULL
GROUP BY tt.testTableId
```

Comment: I was using MIN before, it's not faster